# Fast definition of sparse tensor

Tags: performance-tuning, sparse-arrays, assignment

I'm defining a sparse array through

```
Block[{NN=50, \[Lambda]=1., \[Gamma]=.2, rates},
rates = SparseArray[{}, {NN + 1, NN + 1, NN + 1, NN + 1}, 0];
Do[
  rates[[n + 1, m + 1, n + 1, 
    m + 1]] = -\[Lambda] m (NN - 2 m) - (\[Lambda] + \[Gamma]) (m + n);
  If[m + 2 <= NN + 1 && n >= 1, 
   rates[[n + 1, m + 1, n, m + 2]] = -\[Lambda] (m + 1)^2];
  If[n + 2 <= NN + 1 && m >= 1, 
   rates[[n + 1, m + 1, n + 2, 
     m]] = -\[Lambda] (n + 1) (NN - n - 2 m + 1)];
  If[n + 3 <= NN + 1 && m >= 1, 
   rates[[n + 1, m + 1, n + 3, m]] = \[Lambda] (n + 1) (n + 2)];
  If[n + 2 <= NN + 1, 
   rates[[n + 1, m + 1, n + 2, 
     m + 1]] = (n + 1) (\[Lambda] + \[Gamma]) + 2 \[Lambda] m (n + 1)];
  If[m + 2 <= NN + 1, 
   rates[[n + 1, m + 1, n + 1, m + 2]] = \[Lambda] (m + 1)^2];
  , {n, 0, NN}, {m, 0, NN}];
rates
]
```

`NN` is an integer, `Gamma` and `Lambda` are variables.

This way it is already quite costly to define the tensor. Are there tricks to speed it up? For matrices, I know I can use `DiagonalMatrix`, but what about tensors?

Edit: Following the suggestion in the comments, I tried an alternative version,

```
data = Flatten[
   Join[Table[{n + 1, m + 1, n + 1, 
       m + 1} -> -\[Lambda] m (NN - 2 m) - (\[Lambda] + \[Gamma]) (m +
           n), {n, 0, NN}, {m, 0, NN}],
    Table[{n + 1, m + 1, n, m + 2} -> -\[Lambda] (m + 1)^2, {n, 1, 
      NN}, {m, 0, NN - 1}],
    Table[{n + 1, m + 1, n + 2, 
       m} -> -\[Lambda] (n + 1) (NN - n - 2 m + 1), {n, 0, 
      NN - 1}, {m, 1, NN}],
    Table[{n + 1, m + 1, n + 3, m} -> \[Lambda] (n + 1) (n + 2), {n, 
      0, NN - 2}, {m, 1, NN}],
    Table[{n + 1, m + 1, n + 2, 
       m + 1} -> (n + 1) (\[Lambda] + \[Gamma]) + 
       2 \[Lambda] m (n + 1), {n, 0, NN - 1}, {m, 0, NN}],
    Table[{n + 1, m + 1, n + 1, m + 2} -> \[Lambda] (m + 1)^2, {n, 0, 
      NN}, {m, 0, NN - 1}]]];
rates = SparseArray[data, {NN + 1, NN + 1, NN + 1, NN + 1}, 0];
```

which seems a lot faster, so thanks.

If anything is still less-than-optimal, I'm still interested to hear.

Comment: Why not use [`SparseArray`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html)?

Comment: Daniel, you are missing several definitions here, please provide a complete MWE so that we may better help you answer this question? You have not defined `rates` or `NN`—if you are intending to fill an empty array `rates` this is useful information also. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, will do.

Comment: @CATrevillian do you mean it would be faster if I compiled a list of data and then ran `SparseArray[]` on that list?

Comment: Daniel, if you must precompute your data, then that would certainly be an option, but it would be better to delay creating the data until you are creating the `SparseArray`. It seems that you know the structure of your array ahead of time, and `SparseArray` gives you the mechanism to build an array of such a structure.